# Logstash is unable to find log4j2.properties configuration file

Tags: ruby, logstash, jruby

When trying to run logstash 5 on windows:

> C:\Development\workspace\logstash>C:\Development\Software\logstash-5.1.2\bin\logstash.bat
>   -f robot-log.js

It gives following error:

```
Could not find log4j2 configuration at path /Development/Software/logstash-5.1.2/config/log4j2.properties. Using default config which logs to console
15:03:53.667 [[main]-pipeline-manager] INFO  logstash.filters.multiline - Grok loading patterns from file {:path=>"C:/Development/Software/logstash-5.1.2/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-patterns-core-4.0.2/patterns/aws"}
15:03:53.684 [[main]-pipeline-manager] INFO  logstash.filters.multiline - Grok loading patterns from file {:path=>"C:/Development/Software/logstash-5.1.2/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-patterns-core-4.0.2/patterns/bacula"}
15:03:53.693 [[main]-pipeline-manager] INFO  logstash.filters.multiline - Grok loading patterns from file ...
```

The file is actually present in the directory. Why is logstash unable to find it?

**Note**:
I originally though this was a problem with Ruby using Linux path separator. However, as @Stefan pointed out in comments below, Ruby accepts Linux style paths even on Windows

Comment: AFAIK, Ruby accept `/` as a path separator, even under windows. Are you sure that the separator is causing the problem?

Comment: @Stefan I think so the configuration file is shipped with logstash by default. And I can see that its present at that path.

Comment: @Stefan You were correct. Its not a Ruby problem, but seems to be a bug in logstash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in latest version of logstash. Under `logger.rb` it has following code:

```
def self.initialize(config_location)
        @@config_mutex.synchronize do
          if @@logging_context.nil?
            file_path = URI(config_location).path
            if ::File.exists?(file_path)
              logs_location = java.lang.System.getProperty("ls.logs")
              puts "Sending Logstash's logs to #{logs_location} which is now configured via log4j2.properties"
              @@logging_context = Configurator.initialize(nil, config_location)
            else
              # fall back to default config
              puts "Could not find log4j2 configuration at path #{file_path}. Using default config which logs to console"
              @@logging_context = Configurator.initialize(DefaultConfiguration.new)
            end
          end
        end
      end
```

The call to `URI.path` seems problematic because according to [documentation](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html) it returns `/posts` when the input is `http://foo.com/posts?id=30&limit=5#time=1305298413`

I'm not a Ruby programmer so I have no idea why logstash devs used it here. But simply replacing `file_path = URI(config_location).path` with `file_path = config_location` fixes the problem for me.

```
C:\Development\workspace\logstash>C:\Development\Software\logstash-5.1.2\bin\logstash.bat -f robot-log.js
Sending Logstash's logs to C:/Development/Software/logstash-5.1.2/logs which is now configured via log4j2.properties
[2017-01-24T15:22:04,754][INFO ][logstash.filters.multiline] Grok loading patterns from file {:path=>"C:/Development/Software/logstash-5.1.2/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-patterns-core-4.0.2/patterns/aws"}
[2017-01-24T15:22:04,769][INFO ][logstash.filters.multiline] Grok loading patterns from file {:path=>"C:/Development/Software/logstash-5.1.2/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-patterns-core-4.0.2/patterns/bacula"}
[2017-01-24T15:22:04,772][INFO ][logstash.filters.multiline] Grok loading patterns from file {:path=>"C:/Development/Software/logstash-5.1.2/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-patterns-core-4.0.2/patterns/bro"}
```